# Page Shows Scroll bar no matter what

Tags: css, scroll, scrollbar, hide

Here's my page: http://bad-sf.com/stemtest/about.html

Notice that scrolling is still an option even though the content is small enough to not require scrolling. Could it have to do with my css? (below):

```
body:before {
content:"";
height:100%;
float:left;
width:0;
margin-top:-32767px;
}
* {
margin:0;
padding:0;
outline: none;
}
html, body {
height:100%;
font-family: '_.regular';
font-size: 13px;
outline: none;
}
#wrap {
min-height:100%;
width:800px;
margin: 2% auto;
}
#main {
overflow:auto;
padding-bottom: 30px;
}
#smm {
width: 400px;
height: 200px;
float:left;
}

#footer {
position: relative;
margin-top: 0px;
height: 35px;
clear:both;
font-family: '_.regular';
}
```

THANKS! I'm still learning html and css so any input you have would be really appreciated - Danny

Answer (score 2):

This is caused by `#wrap`, being 104% height. Note these rules:

```
body {
    height: 100%;
}
#wrap {
    min-height: 100%;
    margin: 2% auto;
}
```

So your `#wrap` is actually 100% height plus 2% margin on top plus 2% margin on bottom.

There are several ways of countering this.

You can remove the `height` from `body` and optionally `min-height` from `#wrap`, as it's no use anymore in this case.

You can change `margin` on `#wrap` to `margin: 0 auto;` (this will inevitably raise the content though).

There are probably a few other possibilities, but seeing as the unsatisfactory answers are voted down, I don't really feel compelled towards thinking about more sublime solutions.

Comment: Removing `min-height` from `#wrap` still results in the scrollbar being shown.

Comment: THANKS! Worked like a charm. It was so simple to do, but hard for me to understand with so many factors in play...

Answer (score 0):

Take away `height:100%;` from `html, body { }`. Why did you need it there even anyway?

The reason why the scrollbar is always appearing is because the `#wrap` DIV is also set to 100% height and on top of that, a margin of 2%. This forces your body to be 2% more than 100%.

You can remove the 2% margin from `#wrap` but if you don't want do, removing the `height: 100%;` from `html, body { }` should do the trick.

Comment: This answer should be accepted from the very beginning. I don't understand the downvote. Seeing how another correct answer was downvoted and subsequently deleted, I won't even bother asking WHY...